# custom exception in java: 'cannot find symbol' if not explicitly imported

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

I am trying to catch an Exception in java, however when catching the Exception I get a `cannot find symbol` error. The error is at `catch (ItemNotFoundException infe)` and the compiler complains that `ItemNotFoundException` is no known class (symbol). Do note that `ItemNotFoundException` is a member of the class `FeedController`.

The class which raises the error:

```
public class WebResource {
    public Entry getEntry() {
        String id = "490d6c15";
        try {
            Entry entry = FeedController.getInstance().getEntry(id);
        } catch (ItemNotFoundException infe) {
            return null;
        }
        return FeedController.getInstance().getEntry("490d6c15");
    }
}
```

The FeedController class, which throws the Exception:

```
public class FeedController {
    public Entry getEntry(String id) throws ItemNotFoundException {
        if(!index.containsKey(id)) throw new ItemNotFoundException(id);
        return index.get(id);
    }
    public static class ItemNotFoundException extends Exception {
        public ItemNotFoundException(String id) {
            super(String.format("item with id %s does not exist", id));
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to ruthlessly import everything in WebResource that FeedController imports to eliminate a missing import.

Comment: Surely your stack trace indicates by line number the exact location of the problem in your code. Perhaps including the trace and the suspect line would help.

Comment: oh right, I just realized, I am not being specific enough /what/ is really causing the error: it is the reference to `ItemNotFoundException` in the first code-block (line 6).

Comment: And have you imported it?

Comment: Any chance you're working with Java Content Repository (JCR)? ItemNotFoundException is a bit generic -- anyone could create an exception with that name, so resolving the namespace based on what you're doing seems to be the key here. Try javax.jcr.ItemNotFoundException for starters. Beyond that, figure out what packages you're working with and see if your exception lives there.

Comment: Oha! Yeah, I just realized that the Exception isn't a standard one, but is implemented inside the class `FeedController`. However that one is imported. The exception is a member of the `FeedController` class itself, so do I have to call it like `FeedController.ItemNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 0):

Ruthlessly importing everything imported by the class that throws this exception might not give you the package that contains the exception.  Find the fully qualified name of the exception; it *should* be in the javadoc for the method you're calling.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out I had to explicitly import the custom exception from the class, that is:

```
import feedviewer.controller.FeedController.ItemNotFoundException;
```

Otherwise the compiler would not know where to find the exception.

Note that using `catch (FeedController.ItemNotFoundException e)` would not work. You have to use the actual exception, that's why you have to manually import it.